# Select an n of random numbers from arrays in a dataframe with number replacement with python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a dataframe with 11 columns where each row (rows=800) has an array of len=38000 of float64 numbers. I want to select n=1000 of the numbers in each row of all columns with replacement.

I've done this:

```
  n=1000
  df['rand_sample'] = [np.random.choice(j, size=n, replace=True) for i
  in df for j in df[i]]
```

And it gives me this error:
ValueError: Length of values ​​(8000) does not match length of index (800)

I understand the error, but I don't know why it occurs.

Comment: You have 800x11 arrays. To be clear, for each row, do you want to select 1000 values out of the 11*38000 values to form 800 arrays of 1000 values?

Comment: Welcome to SO! To improve your question and attract answers, please add fully executable code (with representative data and all imports) to reproduce the error message, and include the desired output to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to select 1000 number sample's for each row/column, so for each array.

Comment: So how do you expect to assign 800*11 arrays to a single column?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want 1000 items per row out of the 11 arrays, `concatenate` before sampling:

```
n = 1000
df['rand_sample'] = df.apply(lambda r: np.random.choice(np.concatenate(r), n, replace=True), axis=1)
```